# How do I change the color of the tab bar for one view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a bar tint of white in app delegate for my tab bar, but I need it to be clear on one of the selected indexes. I add the below code to the view controller that needs to be clear, but it stays clear. How do I have it so this only applies to one tab.

```
let tabBar = self.tabBarController?.tabBar
tabBar?.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
tabBar?.backgroundImage = UIImage()
tabBar?.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: do you have tabBarController class?

Comment: Yes I tried setting if selected index in view did load

Comment: check my answer, use delegate

Comment: For transparent tabBar check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61815508/7301439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have UITabBarControllerDelegate you can use

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
                      didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

    guard let index = self.viewControllers?.index(where: { $0 == viewController }) else {
        return
    }
    if index == 1 {
        self.tabBar.barTintColor = .black
    } else {
        self.tabBar.barTintColor = .yellow
    }
}
```

Im'm checkig by index because i have navigation controller and this is easier for me, you can try to use

```
if viewController is MyViewController {
    self.tabBar.barTintColor = .black
} else {
    self.tabBar.barTintColor = .yellow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Set UIColor.clear on one tab and a different color on other tab.

```
let tabBar = self.tabBarController?.tabBar
let tabBarItems = tabBar?.items
if(tabBar?.selectedItem == tabBarItems?[0])
{
    tabBar?.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
}
else
{
    tabBar?.barTintColor = UIColor.red
}
```