# Unable to change the color to tabBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have the following method in the parantTabBarController class: 
There can be seen various attempts made to make the tabBar completely transparent. The only one that worked is the one found at the top.

```
       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.clear
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
//        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blue

//        changeTabBarOpacity()
//        self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(red: 17.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 95.0/255.0, alpha: 0.4)
//        self.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 17.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 95.0/255.0, alpha: 0.0)

//        self.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
//        self.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
//        self.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()  // removes the border

    }
```

However with this approach I am not able to change the background color of this same tabBar in other view controllers. I have tried replacing the image with a white image, changing the background color: `UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white` But nothing works.

**How can I have a translucent tabBar on one page and a white one on all others?**

Comment: Add the appearance code to the AppDelegate didFinishLaunching. viewDidLoad is specific to the one view controller so that changes are not applied to the other views.

Comment: @AkhileshSharma "viewDidLoad is specific to the one view controller so that changes are not applied to the other views" Yes I know but trying to change the background color for the current VC does not even work in these other VCs

Comment: I am not able to get the question here.. Are you trying to change the background color of the tabBar or trying to change the background color of VC? Can you please explain your question a little more here

Comment: @AkhileshSharma Trying to change the background color of the tabbar. BUT also change opacity to 0.0

Answer (score 2):

I use this code to configure tab bar in custom subclass of UITabBarController. It supports iOS 15 and XCode 13 updates.

```
let backgroundColor = UIColor.red
let selectedItemTextColor = UIColor.black
let unselectedItemTextColor = UIColor.white

if #available(iOS 15, *) {
    let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: selectedItemTextColor]
    tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: unselectedItemTextColor]
    tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
} else {
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: selectedItemTextColor], for: .selected)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: unselectedItemTextColor], for: .normal)
    tabBar.barTintColor = backgroundColor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Swift 5 :

Okay i found the solution, the main key is using the `isTranslucent` property of `UITabBar`.

- If you send isTranslucent : true to a tab bar with an opaque custom
  background image the tab bar will apply a system opacity less than 1.0 to the image.

if you want to set clear color then u just have to set `isTranslucent` to true only. and if you want to apply other colors then set `isTranslucent` to false.

Use the below TabBarViewController class to your TabBarViewController

---

```
    class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.delegate = self
            
            self.tabBar.isTranslucent = true
            UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
            
            //This is for removing top line from the tabbar.
            UITabBar.appearance().layer.borderWidth = 0.0
            UITabBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true
        }
    
       // This method will get called when you tap on any tab
        func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
            
            if viewController == tabBarController.viewControllers?[0] { //<----- This is first viewController
                
                //If you set isTranslucent to true then no need to set barTintColor. it will make your tabBar transparent
                self.tabBar.isTranslucent = true
                
            } else if viewController == tabBarController.viewControllers?[1] { //<----- This is second viewController
                
                self.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
                
               // the tab bar will provide an opaque background black for UIBarStyleBlack or white for UIBarStyleDefault if barTintColor is nil.
                self.tabBar.barTintColor = .white
                
                // OR
                
              //  self.tabBar.barTintColor = nil
                
            } else {
                self.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
                self.tabBar.barTintColor = .red
            }
            return true
        }
    }
```

Output : -

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: When I set isTranslucent = false and set a tint color the tab bars background turns black when I hit the bottom of tables scrollview any ideas why that might be @saifan ?

Answer (score 0):

@isa123 try this code in appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
  UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
  UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(named: "PrimaryDark")
  UITabBar.appearance().isOpaque = false
  UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage.init(color: UIColor(named: "PrimaryDark")!, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
```

Answer (score -2):

replace

```
let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
```

to

```
let tabBarAppearance = UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance.copy()
```

working for me!

fullcode:

```
var color : UIColor = UIColor(.red)
     let appearance = UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance.copy()
    
            
            UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color]
            
            UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color]
            
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: color]
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor =  color
           
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor =  UIColor.gray
            
            
            appearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: color]
            appearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]
            appearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor =  color
           
            
            UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
```

Comment: There's no use of `let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()` in the question. What are you replying to?